# How to create a word wrapping program in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to create a program that simulates word wrapping text found in programs like Word or Notepad. If I have a long text, I would like to print out 64 characters (or less) per line, followed by a newline return, without truncating words. Using Windows 10, PyCharm 2018.2.4 and Python 3.6, I've tried the following code:

```
long_str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," \
       "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." \
       "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris" \
       "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in" \
       "reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur." \
       "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui" \
       "officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

concat_str = long_str[:64] # The first 64 characters
rest_str = long_str[65:] # The rest of the string

rest_str_len = len(rest_str)

while rest_str_len > 64:
    print(concat_str.lstrip() + " (" + str(len(concat_str)) + ")" + "\n")
    concat_str = rest_str[:64] 
    rest_str = rest_str[65:] 
    rest_str_len = len(rest_str) 

print(concat_str.lstrip() + " (" + str(len(concat_str)) + ")" + "\n")
print(rest_str.lstrip() + " (" + str(len(rest_str)) + ")")
```

This is so close, but there are two problems. First, the code truncates off letters at the end or beginning of lines, such as the following output:

```
# I've added the total len() at the end of each line just to check-sum.
 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,sed do e (64)'
 'usmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim (64)'
 'ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laborisnisi u (64)'
 'aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor inrepreh (64)'
 'nderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla par (64)'
 'atur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in cul (64)'
 'a quiofficia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. (49)'
```

The second problem is that I need the code to print a newline only after a whole word (or punctuation), instead of chopping up the word at 64 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`textwrap.wrap`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap):

```
import textwrap

long_str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," \
       "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." \
       "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris" \
       "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in" \
       "reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur." \
       "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui" \
       "officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

lines = textwrap.wrap(long_str, 64, break_long_words=False)

print('\n'.join(lines))
```

This takes long string and splits it into lines of a particular width. Also, set `break_long_words` to `False` to prevent splitting of words.

Comment: This works brilliantly and is very efficient! One of the best features of Python is the number of libraries and imports available. However, if I wanted to stubbornly fix my wordy code, could you help me identify the truncation error?

Comment: @Andy, sure. `rest_str = rest_str[65:]` should be `rest_str = rest_str[64:]`. Can you try with this change? Also, `rest_str = long_str[65:]` to `rest_str = long_str[64:]` at the beginning.